# See received emails in Activity History

Tags: email, apex-email-service, email2case

Is there a way i can see all sent and received emails (related to a Case) in its "Activity History"

Email-to-Case shows everything in Email related list. "Activity History" only shows the sent emails.

Email-to-Salesforce seems impractical for this scenario.

From what i understand, "Activity History" is a readonly object, so i doubt i can mess around with it through some code (like create an "ActivityHistory" record for every received email).

Any suggestions? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActivityHistory` is nothing more than either a `Task` or an `Event` record with a closed status. You could write a trigger on `EmailMessage` and create a closed `Task` or an `Event` with the incoming email body.

Comment: Is there a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Bachovski ... so this is how i did it - while setting up a routing address for Email-to-Case, i checked the box of "Create task" with Status as "Complete". So any received email creates a closed task, and now it shows in ActivityHistory